# What does this SMTP Error Mean?

Tags: php, email, smtp, fuelphp

I'm trying to use zoho mail to send email. I receive this this response from my application.

```
[QUIT] expecting: 221 received: 214 RSET NOOP QUIT HELP VRFY
```

My settings:

```
'smtp'  => array(
            'host'      => 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com',
            'port'      => 465,
            'username'  => 'name@domaincom',
            'password'  => '*password*',
            'timeout'   => 10,
        ),
```

Here's the settings preference from their website. https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/imap-access.html

Answer (score 0):

It means your application was expecting a **221** response ( *[domain] Service closing transmission channel* ) but actually got back a **214** ( *Help message* ).

I'd say that your initial connection is failing or sending a malformed connection request.

See here for more: http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/smtpreplies.html

Answer (score 0):

I've double checked the error codes and got the following description:

214
MEANING A response to the HELP command.
WHAT TO DO It contains information about your particular server, normally pointing to a FAQ page.

221
MEANING The server is closing its transmission channel. It can come with side messages like "Goodbye" or "Closing connection".
WHAT TO DO The opposite (on refering page it says oppsite...) of an error; everything has worked and your email has been delivered.

(Copied from http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-error)

The response you get may refer to missing values.

In Zoho I noticed an additionaly parameter which may be required, the email address that needs to be matching the email address or aliases of the account. Have you added that to the configuration?

Comment: Ok, will check to see on this.

Answer (score 0):

For every send command the mailserver has to answer with a status-code. In this case the server answered with 214, which is a part of the help-output.

Its hard to say where the mistake was made with this snipped of your code.
But I guess its not about your smtp-settings. Provide more code for more help.